# Importing contributions with soft credits fails with spurious email error

Tags: import, contributions, 4.6

I'm trying to import some contributions. Each contribution has a soft credit field which is an email address. I've set the field mapping to Soft Credit / Email / Solicited. All the rows are failing with `Invalid email address(doesn't exist) <email> for Soft Credit. Row was skipped` but there are contacts with those email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, covered here on the civibugtracker:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17163?jql=text%20~%20%22import%20email%20soft%20credit%22

Comment: Thanks for that - I'm not sure it's exactly the same bug, but I suspect it is related (probably the next incarnation of it!), and it gives me somewhere to look